# Why is my image not popping up using the code <img> using HTML?

Tags: html, image

The code was just a practice for my html study and the image is not popping up like i want it to i want to know why.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <body>
    <p>
     <h1> This is ur mom texting </h1>
     <p>hello human of the world this is your mom and i disapoprove of you all</p>
     <a href="https://www.google.com">this the link</a>
     <p>
       <img src="f7e55d6f07a6f29a827017134ccc6321.jpg" alt=https://www.google.com width"100" height"100" >
     </p>
 </body>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by popping up ?? what i see is your code is only for displaying a simple photo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this instead

```
<img src="f7e55d6f07a6f29a827017134ccc6321.jpg" alt="https://www.google.com" width="100" height="100" >
```

Yhe syntax of an attribute is as follows

> attributeName="value"

Note the **"** and the **=**

**src** must lead to an image, not just the name of the image
you have to give the link to the image depending on where the HTML file is located
So I supposed that your image is in the same place as the HTML file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).